# Yii2: REST API, 404 ошибка

Tags: php, yii2, rest

В базе данных есть некоторая таблица с сохраненными твитами .

Есть контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class TweetController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Tweet';
}
```

Есть соответствующая модель `app\model\Tweet` созданная в через `gii`.

В `app\web\config` добавлено:

```
..............
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                 'controller' => 'tweet'],
            ],
        ],
        'request' => [
                 'parsers' =>['application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser', ],
        ],
...............
```

В `app\web` добавлен `.htaccess` согласно http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html

В `apache` DocumentRoot прописан `app\web`

Согласно документации: `curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" "http://localhost/tweets"` должен вернуть постраничный вывод данных модели. Вместо этого:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2016 14:04:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 278
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /tweets was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Так же пробовался варианта при urlManager `'controller' => ['tw' => 'tweet']` и соответсвующем url.

Почему выдает 404 ошибку? Руководствовался http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

Comment: Попробуйте так: curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "http://localhost/tweets". А запрашиваемая страница открывается в браузере?